# Spring Boot REST API unrecognized token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, traefik

I have a REST API and a WEB-app that makes request for that API. Both in Spring Boot.
I followed [one of the many guides on this](https://dzone.com/articles/json-web-token-how-to-secure-spring-boot-rest-api) and testing the API in postman worked fine.
I also tested the API from my webapp and it also worked.

But when i run my API in docker with Traefik i get an error, but only from the webapp. Postman still works fine.

```
2020-10-27T13:31:10.334026053Z  at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na],
2020-10-27T13:32:34.827929610Z java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read 
requestcom.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'ssword': was expecting 
(JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

In the request i post username and password as json in the body like this:

```
{
    "username" : "user",
    "password" : "dfgdhghdhdhfd"
}
```

This is the code that generates the request from the webapp:

```
JsonObject j = new JsonObject();
    j.addProperty("username", API_USER);
    j.addProperty("password", API_PASSWORD);

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("http://myapi.local/login"))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(j.toString()))
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2L))
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
        return response.headers().firstValue("Authorization").get();
```

Is there any chance it gets truncated somehow as it refers to the latter half of the 'password' key? I'm unsure of even where to begin getting information to assist you in helping me.

To summarize:

- Localhost webapp and postman to localhost API: Works
- Localhost postman to Docker API: Works
- Localhost webapp to Docker API: Does not work

Comment: Can you sysout "BodyPublishers.ofString(j.toString())" and see if the one sent from postman body and this matches?

Comment: It matches, this is from j.toString: `{"username":"user","password":"dfgdhghdhdhfd"}`